# How can I close fullscreen mode of vlc

Tags: c#, vlc

I need to close vlc fullscreen mode. To open it i did:

```
vlc.fullscreen();
```

I have tried to use the method sendkeys with:

```
sendkeys.sendwait("{ESC}");
```

because with the click of the escape button it,vlc fullscreen mode will close.but it doesn't work. I have tried with `vlc.visibility` but nothing happens.

Comment: Is this in WPF or WinForm?

Comment: What lib do you use to interface VLC ?

Comment: according to this, `vlc.Stop()` should do it: https://wiki.videolan.org/IPlayer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Try not `sendkeys.sendwait("{ESC}");` but `sendkeys.sendwait("{F}");` **F** is shortkey for enter or exit full-screen view.

Maybe you use process. You need `vlcProcess.Exit();`

```
string vlc = @"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
Process vlcProcess = new Process();
vlcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = vlc;
vlcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + videoFile + "\"";
vlcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments += " --play-and-exit";
vlcProcess.Start();
vlcProcess.Exit();
```

Comment: no i don't use process,i have insert the vlc object into an user control,so i don't use process.sorry

Comment: not..it stop the video but it doesn't close the fullscreen mode

Comment: Try not `sendkeys.sendwait("{ESC}");` but `sendkeys.sendwait("{F}");` F is shortkey for enter or exit full-screen view.